# When we create and start a new .NET thread, does it create a new OS level thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When we create a new thread in this way:

```
Threading.Thread t = new Threading.Thread(() => { Console.WriteLine("My New thread"); });
t.Start();
```

Is it going to create an OS level thread as well?

Comment: Well, I am not sure if that should be called an unmanaged thread. But yea probably OS level thread could be called an unmanaged thread only.

Answer (score 12):

Technically this is undefined, a custom CLR host can use any construct to implement a thread.  The underlying hosting interface is [IClrTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Nor is there a decent way to find out.

Practically this never happens.  IClrTask was added at the request of the SQL Server group which wanted the option to map a thread onto a fiber.  That project ultimately failed, they could not get it stable enough.  A red flag to anybody that might have had similar plans.  Unless you are acting as a plugin to a large unmanaged program similar to SQL Server, you can always assume you'll consume an OS thread.